# Setting border color of some part of View

Tags: android, border

I want to paint Fragment View border's left but not whole border. I want to use left buttons as tabs. When clicked on one of them, I want to paint whole borders of button but right and paint view's left corner except button's right side which clicked on.
Is there any way to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can create a nine-patch image that has only the left boarder and apply it as the background of the fragment.

more information on how to create a nine-patch image could be found here:

http://radleymarx.com/blog/simple-guide-to-9-patch/

and here:

http://android9patch.blogspot.co.il/

Comment: this answer wasn't helpful?